# How to add two view controllers to one tab bar item

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to swift. I created a project with `three view controllers`
 - Home page
 - My account
 - Login page
one navigation controller and tab bar controller in storyboard.i connected the `root view controllers` as home page and my account pages .
And my problem is when i click `My account` tab bar item i need to check the user is logged in or not.
If the user is not logged in it should go to `Login page` and vise versa. But it's not happening . please help me....

Comment: Show the code on how you are checking if the user is logged in as well as how you are perform the segue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load the correct view controller when the user tap on the TabBarButton, you have to implement the [UITabBarDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbardelegate).

The method that you are looking for is this one ([see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbardelegate/1623463-tabbar)):

```
func tabBar(UITabBar, didSelect: UITabBarItem)
```

I advise you to implement this delegate and to check if the user is connected when the user select the right item.

I should be something like this:

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item == accountItem, isConnected {
        // show my account
    else if item == accountItem {
        // show login
    }
}
```

Comment: func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

Comment: if tabBarIndex == 1 { if (delegate.UserId ?? "").isEmpty {
                        delegate.strRedrctntag="MyAccountVC"
                        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login VC") as! Login     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true) }else
 {let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyAccountVC") as! MyAccount                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)  }
 }
but not working sir